# Проверка на существование записи в sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Проверяю существует ли запись в бд но все время получаю false (0 с курсора). Проверяю так:

```
public boolean checkMovieExist(int movieId){
    String checkQuery = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM " + FAVORITE_TABLE_NAME
                                                      + " WHERE " + MOVIE_ID + " = " + movieId + " LIMIT 1)";
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(checkQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    boolean isRecordExist;
    isRecordExist = cursor.getInt(0) > 0;
    cursor.close();
    return isRecordExist;
}
```

При этом запись в бд существует.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public boolean recipeIsFavorite(int id) {
        try {
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_FAVORITES + " WHERE " + VALUE + " = " + id + ";";
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                db.close();
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("recipeIsFavorite", e.toString());
        }
        db.close();
        return false;
    }
```